# SwiftUI - custom buttom next to iOS search bar

Tags: swiftui, searchbar

I want to achieve something like this in my SwiftUI project:

[image: something like this:]

I am looking to add a custom button next to the search bar, but I am unable to find relevant information online. Is it possible to achieve this without using custom code, or do I need to use a custom search bar? Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: That's only possible with a custom search bar. There are many tutorials online on how to create a custom search bar so you can take a look at those. You can also wrap a `UISearchTextField` in a `UIViewRepresentable`.

Comment: it could be very simple, it depends what kind of search bar it is. 
For example, is it a `.searchable(...)` or part of a `.toolbar{...}`?
Can you post the code you are using to display your "search" bar.

Comment: Thanks! I'm using a very simple .searchable() modifier. Nothing fancy. It's not part of a .toolbar{}.

Comment: I don't think you can add such button to a `.searchable(...)`.
 I suggest replacing the `.searchable(...)`
 with a `.toolbar{...}` containing a `TextField` and a `Button` in a `HStack`.
 It is very simple to do (have some example code if interested).

Comment: Thanks! I would love to have some code to see how to approach my issue!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this simple all SwiftUI approach, replacing the `.searchable(...)`
with a `.toolbar` containing a `TextField` and a `Button` in a `HStack`.

For example:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    let fruits = ["apples", "pears", "bananas", "apricot", "oranges"]
    @State var selection: String?
    @State var search = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List(selection: $selection) {
                ForEach(fruits.filter{searchFor($0)}, id: \.self) { fruit in
                    Text(fruit).tag(fruit)
                }
            }
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
                    HStack {
                        TextField(" Search", text: $search)
                            .font(.system(size: 22, weight: .light, design: .default))
                            .textFieldStyle(.plain)
                            .background(Color.gray.opacity(0.2))
                            .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5, style: .continuous))
                        
                        Button(action: {
                            print("-----> Button pressed")
                            // ...
                        }) {
                            Image(systemName: "line.3.horizontal.decrease")
                        }
                    }
                    .frame(width: 300, height: 26) // adjust the size to your purpose
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func searchFor(_ txt: String) -> Bool {
        return (txt.lowercased(with: .current).hasPrefix(search.lowercased(with: .current)) || search.isEmpty)
    }
    
}
```